# How to knit rmd to HTML from console?

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse, knitr, readline

In my rmarkdown I use `readline()` and `write.xlsx()`, after running the all chunks next I want to knit/produce HTLM file.
So I wonder if it's possible to put a specific code in the end, in order to run all the chunks, define parameters by readline(), export .csv files and finally knit this .rmd file into HTML?

something likes this:

```
x= readline(prompt = " human input ")

openxlsx::write.xlsx()

knit to html
```

Comment: Do yo mean this: `rmarkdown::render("xxx.Rmd", "html_document")`

Comment: I don't know this package. Does it generates html file?

Answer (score 1):

Do `rmarkdown::render("xxx.Rmd")` in command line. The YAML block in the file determines output format.

> I don't know this package. Does it generates html file?

How come? `rmarkdown` is the package for R Markdown.